# Browsers are changing html markup. How force all browsers to use native markup?

Tags: php, jquery, html, browser, xpath

I have a problem and hope someone can help me.
I use iframe with `src="http://my.own.domain/some/path/file-1"`;

This url send me a content from `"http://some-site.com/path1/path2/path3/qwerty.html"`;

But before sending the content I am pre-proccessing links and resources.

For example if css `<link rel="/css/style1">`, I add protocol and host to it and makes something like `<link rel="http://some-site.com/css/style1">`

After what I'm clicking on some page element and read current node information by js ( name and attributes of current node, name and attributes of parent node and goes up till I see html tag).
This data I send to php script using ajax.
Using php I convert it to XPath selector and see that my selector is incorrect.

```
//html
    /body[0]
    /div[@id='wrap']
    /div[@id='main']
    /table[contains(@class, 'content-wrapper')][1]
    /tbody[1]
    /tr[1]
    /td[contains(@class, 'content-wrap')][1]
    /div[contains(@class, 'content')][1]
    /div[contains(@class, 'node')][1]
    /div[contains(@class, 'techs')][1]
    /table[1]
    /tbody[1]
    /tr[4]
    /td[contains(@class, 'techs-right')][1]
```

But native markup of that page is:

```
//html
        /body[0]
        /div[@id='wrap']
        /div[@id='main']
        /table[contains(@class, 'content-wrapper')][1]
             /*/tbody[1] - without this*/
        /tr[1]
        /td[contains(@class, 'content-wrap')][1]
        /div[contains(@class, 'content')][1]
        /div[contains(@class, 'node')][1]
        /div[contains(@class, 'techs')][1]
        /table[1]
             /*/tbody[1] - without this*/
        /tr[4]
        /td[contains(@class, 'techs-right')][1]
```

It seems like browser is modifying incorrect markup and makes it correct.. But this is a hitch for me. How to turn this off?

Comment: I'm inclined to say you can't. But you can skip the `tbody` element in the path expression: `//table//tr`.

Comment: So, would this be a possible solution? Can you manipulate this path expression?

Comment: I think I will exclude from xpath each node what have no any attribute, and where count of this node type inside it's parent node is 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how this is an answer to my question.

Comment: Your answer helps me to find solution.

Comment: _“It seems like browser is modifying incorrect markup and makes it correct”_ – not quite. The `tbody` is not _required_ in HTML, but in the DOM every table _has_ one – browsers simply generate it automatically when it is not explicitly given, but this is no “error”.